# The IME functionality mapping to TSF

Tags: c#, com

I've got  questions about mapping IME functionality to TSF.

1. It seems msctf.dll cannot be imported automatically by tlbImp,how can I use this com component? Must I  manually define c# managed wrapper of it?
2. I want to implement `ImmSetOpenStatus` in TSF way,I find `ITfInputProcessorProfiles.ActivateLanguageProfile` and `ITfThreadMgr.Activate`,which one should I use? And which sink should I use to implement `IMN_SETOPENSTATUS` notify?
3. I use `IMN_OPENCANDIDATE` and `IMN_CLOSECANDIDATE` notify message to know when to call ImmGetCandidateList in legacy,how can I implement in TSF? （which sink should I listen? And then call `ITextStoreACPServices::CreateRange-->ITfFnReconversion::QueryRange-->ITfFnReconversion::GetReconversion-->ITfCandidateList?)`
4. which level of compartment should I replaced for `IMN_SETCONVERSIONMODE` to be notified the change of language bar,the global, thread,Document,or context?

Well,it's a lot of questions,it's appreciate if someone could give me some advices.